# Simple Rspec test failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following model:

```
module CgCart
  class ShippingInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'cg_cart.shipping_infos'
    has_many :order, :class_name => "CgCart::Order"
    accept_nested_attributes_for :orders, :allow_destroy => true
    validates_presence_of :name, :street, :city, :country, :zip, :state

def to_s
    retval = <<-formatted_addr
    #{self.name}
    #{self.street}
    #{self.city} #{self.state} #{self.zip}
    #{self.country}
      formatted_addr
      retval.upcase
    end
  end
end # module
```

I am writing a spec test. It goes like this:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../spec_helper'
describe CgCart::ShippingInfo do
    context "when first created" do
        it "should be empty" do
            @shipping_info = CgCart::ShippingInfo.new
            @shipping_info.should be_empty
        end
    end
end
```

When I run the spec test I get the following error:

```
1)
NoMethodError in 'CgCart::ShippingInfo when first created should be empty'
undefined method `be_empty' for #<Spec::Matchers::PositiveOperatorMatcher:0x105f165c0>
./spec/models/cg_cart/shipping_info_spec.rb:6:

Finished in 0.015 seconds

1 example, 1 failure
```

This seems like it should very straight forward. Any ideas on why this test fails?

Comment: You haven't defined an `empty?` method for `CgCart::ShippingInfo` instances. What exactly do you want to test? probably `@shipping_info.orders.should be_empty`?

Comment: I thought the empty method was already defined. What I want to test is that when I create a new shipping_info object it is empty. There shouldn't need to be the presence of an order object since shipping_info has many orders.

Comment: How do you define that a shipping_info object is empty?  Is it empty if it doesn't have any orders; or is it empty if any of it's attributes are nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use empty where I should have been using nil.

```
@shipping_info.should be_nil
```